# Nuitkaの名前の由来が知りたい

Tags: python

不思議な名前だと思います！
どうやったら調べられるかも教えてもらえると助かります！

Answer (score 3, accepted):

タグから[Python製PythonコンパイラーのNuitka](https://pypi.org/project/Nuitka/)のことかなと解釈しましたが、この名前の由来は作者であるKay Hayen氏の妻のニックネームから来ています。

[Xでの投稿がきっかけで作者本人によって由来が紹介されており](https://twitter.com/KayHayen/status/1028940741047930880) 、現在は[Nuitkaのドキュメント内](https://nuitka.net/doc/Credits.html)にも由来に関する内容が記述されています。

※この手の「提供機能との関連性が感じられない」タイプの名前については、今回のようにドキュメントなどに記載されているケースがあったりします。もしくは、今回同様に作者に直接聞いてしまうのも一つの手段となるでしょう。

Comment: 完璧です！ありがとうございます！